# Managing View -> Controller interaction on MVC without frameworks?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how MVC works on PHP. On Java and Swing based programs, or with winforms in C#, my views fire events, to which the controllers or the presenters subscribe, and in response perform an action. However, PHP lacks events. I'd implement them a la java, but I can't understand how to achieve MVC when I can't fire a method as a response for a hyperlink click.

So far I'm checking for POST and GET variables at the start() method of my controllers, and responding in a specific way. For example, if $_POST isn't set, display the user registration view. Otherwise, register the user with the POST variables.

I know there has to be a better way to do it, but I can't find anything on the web explaining the view -> controller relationship on PHP.

How do you manage this?

Comment: Do be aware that a web app (even in C#) is quite different than a desktop app. Sure, the webforms tried to mimic the desktop approach but that clearly is not suitable for a web app hence the asp.net mvc.
There are MVC frameworks in php too (code igniter, Symfony etc) so use them but the most important thing is to understand how the web works and why the click event on a view is an abomination.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand how to achieve MVC when I can't fire a method as a
>   response for a hyperlink click.

Within your router you can use the [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) function, so something like:

```
<?php 
if(file_exists($controller)){
    include($controller);
    $this->controller = new $this->controller($this);
    //check method exists within loaded controller
    if(method_exists($this->controller, $this->action)){
        $this->controller->{$this->action}($this);
    }
}
?>
```